# SharePoint Online, uploading files larger than 2mb using SharePointClient

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, large-files

While trying to upload files to SharePoint online, remotely via `SharePointClient` `upload`, I am encountering a file size limit of 2mb. From my searches it seems that people have overcome this limit using `PowerShell`, but is there a way to overcome this limit using the native `SharePointClient` package in .Net C#? Here is my existing code sample:

```
    using (var ctx = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(httpUrl))
    {
        ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
        try
        {
            string uploadFilename = string.Format(@"{0}.{1}", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename) ? submissionId : filename, formatExtension);
            logger.Info(string.Format("SharePoint uploading: {0}", uploadFilename));
            new SharePointClient().Upload(ctx, sharePointDirectoryPath, uploadFilename, formatData);
        }
    }
```

I have read from the following site that you can use the ContentStream just not sure how that maps to `SharePointClient` (if at all):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint

**UPDATE:**

Per the suggested solution I now have:

```
public void UploadDocumentContentStream(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string filePath)
{

    Web web = ctx.Web;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();

        // This is the key difference for the first case - using ContentStream property
        flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs;
        flciNewFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;

        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

        ctx.Load(uploadFile);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Still not quite working, but will update again when it is successful. Current error is :

```
Could not find file 'F:approot12-09-2017.zip'.
```

**FINALLY**

I am using files from Amazon S3 so the solution was to take my byte data and to stream that to the call:

```
public void UploadDocumentContentStream(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string filename, byte[] data)
{

    Web web = ctx.Web;
    FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    flciNewFile.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(data); ;
    flciNewFile.Url = filename;
    flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;
    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);
    ctx.Load(uploadFile);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FileCreationInformation` to create a new file and provide the contents via a `FileStream`. You can then add the file to the destination library. This should help you get around 2mb limit you are encountering with upload method you are using. Example below:

```
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation
{
    Url = fileName,
    Overwrite = false,
    ContentStream = new FileStream(fileSourcePath, FileMode.Open)
};

var createdFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
ctx.Load(createdFile);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

In the example the destination library is `list` you will need to get reference to this first. I can show you how to do this if required.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it try tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: There is one thing to keep in mind, timeout occurs after 30 minutes with this method. Microsoft guidance is to use filestream upload for files upto 10mb, but you could getaway with more. Let me know if you are still encountering issues and I will provide an example for the Start, Continue, Finish upload method.

Comment: Hi, so I have tried a slightly modified version of what you suggested. See the Updated above. However I am seeing the following error from SharePoint:SharePoint Error: Could not find file 'F:approot12-09-2017.zip'. Where the file I am uploading is "12-09-2017.zip". Where is the "F:approot" coming from?

Comment: What does the `filePath` variable contain? Does the code exception? If so, which line do you see the error?

Comment: I think the problem is that I am referencing S3 files, so rather than using a File option I need to stream the byte array I have to the call.